# How can I use Display Name attribute with GridView when exporting to Excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I want to set the Column header text with [DisplayName()] attribute when I export the List to Excel file.
any solution ?

```
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSource = ExportList;

gv.DataBind();

 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Rapor.xls");
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
gv.RenderControl(htw);
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use `RowDataBound` event of grid like this:
First put this line after creating gv:

```
gv.RowDataBound+=GvOnRowDataBound;
```

Then follow this code:

```
private void GvOnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count;i++)
        {
            var customAttributes =
                typeof (YourClass).GetProperty(e.Row.Cells[i].Text).CustomAttributes.ToList();
            var displayNameAttribute =
                customAttributes.FirstOrDefault(
                    aa => aa.AttributeType.FullName.Equals("System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute"));
            if (displayNameAttribute != null)
                e.Row.Cells[i].Text = displayNameAttribute.ConstructorArguments[0].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Remember change `YourClass` to the name of your class.

Comment: Thanks... It saved me a lot of time. Just a couple observations to help others: 
1 - Call it before call the DataBind() method.
2 - To remove the (") from the headers texts replace line in code to -> e.Row.Cells[i].Text = displayNameAttribute.ConstructorArguments[0].Value.ToString();